# Have I Found an Error in "Game Theory" by Hans Peters?

Tags: game-theory, decision-trees

I am reading the book *Game Theory: A Multileveled Approach* Second Edition by Hans Peters. It appears to be the most recent copy. I've search here and on Google for a list of known errors in the book, but couldn't find any.

In section 1.3.3.1 *Sequential Battle of the Sexes* there is a decision tree in figure 1.1. The tree looks like this:

[image: recreation of figure 1.1 from Game Theory by Hans Peters]

**Setup (paraphrased from the book)**
The *Story* here is similar to the original Battle of the Sexes only this time we assume that man chooses first and the woman can observe the choice of the man.

I am new to game theory. I'm trying to make sure I understand this and I'm not missing something. Should the rightmost decision tree of player 2 be F(B) not F(F) (I hope I worded that right)? I started to think that maybe I didn't understand the difference between the two scenarios (the woman knows what the man chooses vs. she doesn't know). Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. It should be $F$ and $B$ on the right side subgame just as it is on the left. It looks like it's just a typo in the book that both are labeled $F$.

In terms of understanding it, keep in mind that a strategy for P2 defines what she would choose at each of her information sets. Here, she has two information sets, so her strategy set is $S_2 = \{FF,FB,BF,BB\}$, where, by convention, the first letter denotes the action she will choose if P1 chooses $F$ and the second letter denotes what she will choose contingent on P1 playing $B$.